# how can the following line be written in cshtml server side code?

Tags: javascript, html, client-side, server-side

`<script>
          function a(id)
          {
          var table = document.getElementById(id);
          ....
          }
     </script>`

```
@{
   //trying to rewrite the line "var table = document.getElementById(id)" at here
 }
```

May I know if this is possible? Is there any similar code for the server side?

Comment: Does Razor even parse the HTML parts into a DOM tree?  Seems that'd slow things down in the much-more-common case of just outputting stuff.

Comment: sorry I'm newbie, I don't get you.
I was trying to call the function in the script tag but failed as I couldn't pass the server side variable to the client side and now, I'm trying to rewrite the function in the @{}, any ideas?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't just rewrite client-side code on the server; it doesn't know much at all about the full document.  You can easily pass a server-side variable to the client, though... either JSON-encode it and write it into a script, or write it into an element in the page and have JS retrieve the element's contents.

Comment: @cHao, i think he just need to know is there any possibility write code or not..? Nothing else, may he haven't face this type of problem. Right?

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is how to pass service side variable to the js code, an alternative way can do the job.
1. wrap the service side variable in a html tag, e.g.

in html code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ssv" value="<% $id %>"/>
```

in js code:

```
var el = document.getElementById('ssy');
a(el.value);
```